# How to put a Javascript event on something?

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I have a pre-made layout, cannot be changed. But I must put an `onload()` event to `<BODY>`. As I said, I'm not allowed just add `"onload = sdfsdf"` event. Then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.onload = function(){ ... }`. That has the equivalent result as `<body onload="...">`.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a script to attach the event (i suppose that your problem is that you have no control over the html):

```
<script>
document.body.onload = function(){};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29

Answer (score 1):

You can register events on the body through a (java)script using:

`document.body.<event name> = function(){ // whatever your function does  };`

Comment: Nitpicking, but it's `on<event name>`. The event name itself is without `on`.

Comment: well yes, if you read it that way :) ... but I've generally heard people associate the entire string "on..." as the event name. Anyway, quite a personal convention.

Comment: It doesn't matter much; just make sure you pass it without `on` in case you use `addEventListener` :)

Answer (score 0):

put all your code in an function that autoexecute:

```
(function () {
    //your code here
})();
```

and put it at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make everything by yourself, without jQuery. [MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture<Optional>);
```

Depending on the required effect, listener:

1. DOMContentLoaded - loading of the DOM
2. load - loading of all the resource on the page - useful if the page contains large images